# Ran test for ligthdm bug Says Xserver no path found

Tags: 22.04, xorg, xserver

[image: command startx][image: ls -l with Xorg][image: Ran ls -l not 1 and ran grep path]I Ran bug test on lightdm Say Xserver no path i'm stuck on tty1 please help i'm new to Ubuntu and dont know much [image: part 1 of bug test]
[image: part 2 of bug test]
[image: more info]

Comment: Please run `ls -l /usr/bin/X` (that's "minus ell" not "minus one" and upper case `X` not lower case `x`). As well `grep` on its own is not useful - if you want to know why `X` is not found in the path you need to run something like `grep PATH /etc/environment`

Comment: Ok run and Says does not exist

Comment: I uploaded photo of commands

Comment: OK so how about `ls -l /usr/bin/Xorg` (again please be careful with the capitalization)

Comment: Did and Say does not exist i added photo

Comment: So your system seems to be missing the `xserver-xorg-core` package (or at least, some of its files). What flavor of Ubuntu 22.04 is it exactly? Can we assume it's not the standard desktop installation (which would use gdm3 and Wayland iirc, rather than lightdm and Xorg)?

Comment: I'm on ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS reléase 22.04 codename: Jammy on xfce desktop